# SQL to extract the string between the braces (multiple braces could be there)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following column data

```
NZ(abc_mode) / (NZ(bch_mode) + NZ(cdh_mode))
```

Now I need a query to extract the string inside the braces NZ() with or without using regular expressions in SQL.

The output should be

```
abc_mode
bch_mode
cdh_mode
```

Comment: No, one is here to do your homeworks. First tell us what you have tried?

Comment: These `()` are parentheses or (round) brackets; '[]' are (square) brackets; '{}' are braces or curly brackets.  Your question asks about braces, but the material doesn't include any braces.  Did you mean parentheses?

Comment: This would be building a lexer in Oracle.  Perhaps the one Oracle uses has public entry points?

Comment: Split out your data items into rows of columns *before* you put it into your table.

Comment: @onedaywhen, +1 unfortunately too many questions on SO are generated by organisations storing data items as strings when they actually need them split out at a later date.

Answer (score 2):

This is far from elegant but it will return the results you want:

```
WITH t1
  AS (SELECT RTRIM(
              REGEXP_REPLACE('NZ(abc_mode) / (NZ(bch_mode) + NZ(cdh_mode)) ',
                            '([^[:alpha:]]{0,})(\({0,}NZ\()(([[:alpha:]]|\_){1,})(\){1,} {0,})', 
                            '\3,'), 
             ',') AS str
       FROM dual)
SELECT val
  FROM t1,
       XMLTABLE( '/root/e/text()'
                 PASSING xmltype( '<root><e>' || 
                                  REPLACE( t1.str, ',', '</e><e>' ) || 
                                  '</e></root>' )
                 COLUMNS val VARCHAR2( 10 ) PATH '/'
            )
```

Note that I have used 'NZ(abc_mode) / (NZ(bch_mode) + NZ(cdh_mode)) ' as a literal, you'd need to replace this with the column name that holds the string and replace "dual" with the table that contains the column etc.

As this is messy I'll disect it for you:
The WITH clause sets up the data for the SELECT

```
WITH t1
  AS (<SQL STATEMENT>)
```

The REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('NZ(abc_mode) / (NZ(bch_mode) + NZ(cdh_mode)) ',
               '([^[:alpha:]]{0,})(\({0,}NZ\()(([[:alpha:]]|\_){1,})(\){1,} {0,})', 
               '\3,')
```

Takes the string and searches for (pattern sections in brackets):

(Section 1) none or more non-alpha characters

(Section 2) none or more brackets the string "NZ("

(Section 3) one or more alpha or underscore characters

(Section 4) one or more closing brackets followed by none or more spaces

It then replaces the matched pattern with whatever was identified in section 3 and a comma is added to it.

Still with me? OK...

The result of the REGEX is then TRIMMED to remove the trailing comma.

```
RTRIM(<regex_result>, ',')
```

The result of all this is aliased "str" (though you might want to give it a more descriptive name).

The "str" value is then split into columns breaking on the comma by the main SELECT statement.

Hope this helps...